# What is the probability for new born?

Tags: probability

In the end of the first day there are $3$ new male born and $k>0$ new female born.

In the second day there is only one born (male or female) with the same probability.

We choose a new born randomly from all the new born (First and second day).

What is the probability that the new born in the second day is male given that the new born that was chosen was male new born ?

I keep getting the answer $\frac{1}{7}$ but the answer in the book is $\frac{4}{7}$ and i know that my answer is incorrect because without the conditional probability, the probability is already $\frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the second day child were male, the probability that a randomly chosen child was male would be $$\frac 4{4+k}$$

If the second day child were female, the probability that a randomly chosen child was male would be $$\frac 3{4+k}$$

Since these are equally probable (by assumption) the total probability that the randomly chosen child is male is the sum $$\frac 7{2(4+k)}$$

The portion of that which is explained by the second day child being male is $\frac 4{2(4+k)}$ so the answer to your question is  $$\frac { 4\big /(8+2k)}{7\big /(8+2k)}=\frac 47$$

Comment: $P(M | I) = \frac{3}{3+k}$ and $P(M | II) = \frac{1}{2}$ and $P(I) = \frac{3+k}{4+k}$ and $ P( II ) = \frac{1}{4+k}$ so $ P( M ) = \frac{7}{2(4+k)}$ (which fits with your answer), $ P(II | M) = \frac{P(M | II) P(II)}{ P (M)} = \frac{1}{7}$ , what is wrong with my method ?

Comment: The child might be male even if you do not choose him.